# Probability of combinations

Tags: probability

I am encountering a situation that essentially boils down to this:
There are M people. They are randomly assigned to N chairs. What is the probability that no two persons are assigned the same chair (probability that all are assigned separate chairs).

Comment: Any restriction on M and N ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{N(N-1)\dots(N-M+1)}{N^M}$

Comment: Your answer should just be $\frac{N(N-1)\dots(N-M+1)}{N^M}$ because he is asking for probability that no two or more people are assigned the same chair.

Comment: @svenkatr: Yes, indeed.

Comment: It is another example of the Birthday problem: for $M=23$ and $N=365$ it give $0.4927\ldots$, slightly less than a half. It might be worth noting that this expression correctly gives 0 whenever  $M>N$.

Comment: M=N is okay too

Answer (score 0):

This seems correct. For , Total number of permutations is $N^M$ where repetitions are allowed and $N(N-1)(N-2)\cdots(N-M+1)$ are permutations where repetitions are not allowed.